# Laravel, validator com multiplos fields e {{old}}

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho esse código com $n fields de formulário. Não estou conseguindo usar o validator;{

```
public function salvar()
          {
    $n =Request::input('campos');
    for($i=1; $i < $n; $i++){

    $pontosa =Request::input('pontosa'.$i);
    $pontosb =Request::input('pontosb'.$i);
    $validator = Validator::make(
      [ "'pontosa'.$i" => $pontosa,
        "'pontosb'.$i" => $pontosb
      ],
      [
        'pontosa.$i' => 'required|numeric',
        'pontosb.$i' => 'required|numeric'
      ]
    );
    if($validator->fails()){
      return redirect()->action('UsersController@lista');
    }
    $pontuacao =new Listadepontos();
    $pontuacao->pontosa = $pontosa;
    $pontuacao->pontosb = $pontosb;
    $pontuacao->save();
}}
```

Também não consigo manter os dados preenchidos com o {{old}} pois os campos são gerados a partir de um foreach

```
name="<?php echo 'pontosa'.$n; ?>"
```

Não estou me acertando. já tentei diversas formulas de fazer o {{old}} cm as variáveis mas não consegui!

```
<form action="{{ action('UsersController@salvar') }}" method="POST">
  <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-inverse" style="text-align:center">
  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{ csrf_token() }}}">
$n=1;
 foreach($jogos as $j){ ?>
<tr>
<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="<?php echo 'pontosa'.$n; ?>" value="{{old????}}" > </td>

<input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="<?php echo 'pontosb'.$n; ?>" value="{{old???}}" ></td>
      </tr>

<?php $n++; } ?>


    <input type="hidden" name="campos" value="<?php echo $n;?>">
```

Comment: Mostre o formulário?

Comment: Editei com formulário

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Neste Validator do Laravel, qual é a syntax certa? Com variavel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241153/neste-validator-do-laravel-qual-%c3%a9-a-syntax-certa-com-variavel)